# Loop through dataset to calculate diveristy

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a dataset like so:

```
 set.seed(1345)
 df<-data.frame(month= c(rep(1,10), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 10)), 
           species=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 30, replace= TRUE))
```

I would like to loop through each month and calculate species diversity. I am aware of functions like `diversity` in `library("vegan")`, and know solutions to my question using that route (code provided below), but as an exercise for myself with loops I am trying to  create a `for loop` or function that shows the specific calculations for Shannons diversity and Simpsons Diversity so that the calculations for each index are not mysterious. They are calculated using the following formulas:

[image]

Thus far I have tried the following for Simpsons:

```
df <- 
 df %>% 
  group_by(month, species) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n()) 

div<-NA
 for (i in length(unique(df$month))) {
 sum<- sum(df$freq)
 for (i in unique (df$freq)){
 p<- df$freq /sum
 p.sqrd<-p*p
 div[i]<-1/sum(p.sqrd)
   }}
```

And the following for Shannons:

```
df <- 
 df %>% 
  group_by(month, species) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n()) 

div<-NA
 for (i in length(unique(df$month))) {
 sum<- sum(df$freq)
 for (i in unique (df$freq)){
 p<- df$freq /sum
 log.p<-ln(p)
 div[i]<- sum(p[i]*ln(p[i]))
   }}
```

I am not creating a successful loop and would like help indexing this loop correctly and creating one that is most efficient (i.e. incorporating  `df <- df %>% group_by(month, species) %>% summarise(freq = n())` into the loop) and a for loop that clearly illustrates the equation within the loop.

Using the the `diversity` function, here are the answers for Simpson's diversity:

```
library("tidyverse")
df <- 
 df %>% 
 group_by(month, species) %>% 
 summarise(freq = n()) 

# Cast dataframe of interaction frequencies into a matrix
library("reshape2")
ph_mat<- dcast(df,  month~ species)
ph_mat[is.na(ph_mat)] <- 0 #changes 

library("vegan")
df<- data.frame(div=diversity(ph_mat, index="simpson"), 
               month=unique(ph_mat$month))
```

And for Shannons:

```
library("vegan")
df<- data.frame(div=diversity(ph_mat, index="shannon"), 
               month=unique(ph_mat$month))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution here that does not incorporate for loops, but where I define and explain a function to calculate each index (no mystery!) It calculates each diversity metric for each month. It uses the `group_by()` and `summarize()` functions from `dplyr`.

```
set.seed(1345)
df<-data.frame(month= c(rep(1,10), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 10)), 
               species=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 30, replace= TRUE))

calc_shannon <- function(community) {
  p <- table(community)/length(community) # Find proportions
  p <- p[p > 0] # Get rid of zero proportions (log zero is undefined)
  -sum(p * log(p)) # Calculate index
}

calc_simpson <- function(community) {
  p <- table(community)/length(community) # Find proportions
  1 / sum(p^2) # Calculate index
}

diversity_metrics <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarize(shannon = calc_shannon(species),
            simpson = calc_simpson(species))
```