# Vectorizing function to calculate entropy

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm writing a function to calculate a Shannon diversity index. I have wide data with the pct of observations for each value as separate variables, with each row representing a different site. I will have between 2 and 7 variables depending on the data set. For each row I want to calculate the information index.

[image: equation].

I have a loop function, but its quite slow and am looking for help to vectorize it. I'm also happy for a tidyverse style solution.

I've been looking at using the `entropy` package, but it seems to expect the data in long form, and while I could expand my data back out, that seems like it would be unnecessarily slow. I currently have 20k sites with 100's to 1000's of observations per site that have already been summarized into the wide format percent distributions. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546514/loop-through-dataset-to-calculate-diveristy) similarly works with long form data.

## Example data

```
# Wide data, between 2 and 7 columns recording the percent of observations with each value, example using 3
df <- data.frame(
  site = 1:3, 
  l1 = c(.33, .5, 0), 
  l2 = c(.33, .5, 0), 
  l3 = c(.33, 0, 1)
)
```

## Current loop function

```
entropy <- function(df, vars) {

  entropy_calc <- function(df, i, vars) {
    sum <- 0
    for (j in vars) { 
      x <- df[i,j]
      if(x != 0) { # skip zeros
        sum <- sum + x * log(x)
      }
    }
    return(-sum)
  }

  entropy <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    entropy[i] <- entropy_calc(df, i, vars)
  }

  return(as.numeric(entropy))
}

df$entropy <- entropy(df, 2:4)
```

Comment: You can vectorize this very easily. You don't need to manually skip zeroes because when you multiply 0 by the `-Inf` that is returned by `log(0)`, it will return `NaN` which you can omit when summing the cell values. `entropy <- function(p) rowSums(-(p * log(p)), na.rm = TRUE)` then call `entropy(df[,2:4])`

Comment: That is a beautifully simple solution.

Comment: @qdread You should post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be vectorized easily because the underlying functions needed are already vectorized. You don't need to manually skip zeroes because `log(0)` returns `-Inf` and `0*log(0)` returns `NaN`. You can omit the `NaN` when summing the cell values by specifying `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
entropy <- function(p) rowSums(-(p * log(p)), na.rm = TRUE)

entropy(df[,2:4])
```

Also check out the `diversity()` function in the `vegan` package which does essentially this, among other possibilities.